# Is there a pattern of removed skin parts that is connected to wearoff percantage?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I know that the weapon skins have an internal wearof scale ranging from 0 to 100. I'm wondering, (since I own a awp hyperbeast with ~25% wearoff which just looks on playerside like factory new ~ minimal wear. But on the back side its kinda... "battle scared"), is there a pattern for each weapon type where the weapons skin is sratched away? Or has every skin object its individual pattern?

In other words:

lets say My AWP Hyper Beast has a specific wearoff of 25.029371 would it look identical or different from some one elses AWP Hyper Beast with a specific wearoff of 25.029371? My asumption is it would look diferent and I just had luck with my pattern, because otherwise the whole AWP Hyper Beast skin pattern would be kind of... flawless, by just wearing of the whole backside before the players side gets any scratches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wear strictly comes from the float value, the lower the float, the lower the wear.

However, some skins wear more than other : AWP Worm Gods are rarely scratched, while USP Orions always are, even with 0.001 FV

**Identical FV (in your case 25.029371) -> Identical wear** (scratches at the same position, same size.

The scratches are determined per skin with an algorithm, which we may call wear pattern.

This wear pattern is spread on all the weapon (front and back side), with the most used parts of the gun being worn first (handle, clip, butt and barrel)

Check this link and scroll to see the weapon wearing: [CSGO Stash, AK Vulcan skin](https://csgostash.com/skin/354/AK-47-Vulcan)

This does not apply to patterns, such as Case Hardened, Crimson Web and such as far as I know

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by FV but I mean if the wear determines the positions of the scratches or if it just determines the amount of scratches.

Comment: Float value, the " 25.029371" you mention. The value determines the amount, and the position depends on the skin. The wear algorithm is different for each skin

Comment: Ah ok, maybe I formulated my question not understandable. What I actually intended to ask for, was that I was assuming the wear off as FV determines how much of the skin actually is worn off (so 'overlayed' by scratches) And I was asking if this exact  "25.029371"% as in my case, would be also dtermining the position of the scratches or if the same FV for the same skin would still let it be possible that 1 might have this  exposed 25.029371% on hte backside and another individual of the same skin has its 25.029371% exposed on the front side. Or would the location of scratch be identical?

Comment: If you would edit that information into your answer stated in a way I can udnerstand it with certainity, thats enough for me to accept your answer. anyway thanks so far for your investigation ;)

Comment: Should be clear i guess ;)

Comment: Crimson web it definetly applys. I bought a battlescared (~80% wear off stattrack butterfly) Becuase I was liking the way how the remaining red looked like blot splattering. Sadly the killcount is wirtten in silverish metal colour on... well... metall.... you actually CANT see it... -.- . What you were refering to probibly was marble fade. I never even saw them with lower grade as minimal wear. and I just unboxed last wekk 2 of them (:D :D :D) one mw with 8% one FN with 2% And I couldn't find any scratch on any of them.

Comment: I mean, I don't know if the pattern (not the scratch one, but the cobweb one, or blue pattern for a case hardened) is due to the float value or if it's something else.